# How can I download data from Java back-end?

Tags: java, jquery

I request json or xml data from the server.

I console log and for JSON I see json data and for XML i see #Document

How do I download this data to a file json file and xml respectivily?

Java

```
@RestController
    public class RestCtrl {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value="getJSON", method = RequestMethod.GET , produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    List<Map<String, Object>> getJSONData(@RequestParam String query) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> data = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM TICKETS");
        return data;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="getXML", method = RequestMethod.GET , produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    List<Map<String, Object>> getXMLData(@RequestParam String query) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> data = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM TICKETS");
        return data;
    }
}
```

Jquery

```
  $('#download').click(function () {
   var query = $('#query').val();
   var type = $('#type').val();

   console.log('/get' + type);
   $.ajax({
       type: 'get',
       url: '/get' + type,
       data: {query: query},
       success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          //download the file
       },
       error: function () {
           $('#message').html('Error downloading the file')
       }

   })
});
```

Comment: Are you setting the content disposition anywhere?

Comment: no. I just have this code.

Comment: Basically I just want to execute the query and download xml or json data (based on the type selected) into a file something.json or something.xml.